# Как получить переменную вне цикла?

Tags: php

Имеется функция следующего вида. Цикл в ней не возвращает переменную

```
public function actionCheckqiwipayment(){
    if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $wallet = $data['wallet']; //QIWI кошелек
        $amount = $data['qiwi'];
        $currency = $data['currency'];
        $crawler = new QiwiCrawler;
        //Получаем 10 последних платежей
        $payments = $crawler->getPaymentsHistory('number','api-key');
        //var_dump($payments);
        //Проверяем каждый платёж
        for($i=0; $i>=9; $i++){
            $qiwiWallet = $payments['data']["$i"]['account']; //QIWI номер отправителя
            $qiwiAmount = $payments['data']["$i"]['sum']['amount']; //QIWI сумма платежа
            $qiwiCurrency = $payments['data']["$i"]['sum']['currency']; //QIWI Валюта
            $qiwiPaymentType = $payments['data']["$i"]['type']; //Тип платежа
            $qiwiPaymentStatus = $payments['data']["$i"]['status']; //Статус платежа (IN / OUT)

            //Коды валют в API переводим в использующиеся на сайте


            if($qiwiWallet == $wallet && $qiwiAmount == $amount && $qiwiCurrency == $currency && $qiwiPaymentType == 'IN'){
                if($qiwiPaymentStatus == 'SUCCESS'){



                }
                $result = 1;

            }
            else{
                $result = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;




    }
  }
```

Comment: цикл for не будет выполнен. Вам нудно переписать условия в цикле для переменной $i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкция [return](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php) используется для возврата значения в функции. В Вашем случае, Вы через цикл `for`, в зависимости от условий, переписываете переменную `$result`.

И есть подозрение, что цикл не будет выполнен. Начальное значение переменной `$i` меньше указанного значение в условии цикла.

```
for($i=0; $i>=9; $i++){    
}
```

Если идет вызов скрипта через **ajax**, нужно выводить значение а не возвращать:

```
// return $result;    
echo $result;
```

Comment: Ну да, я её переписываю, но мне ничего не возвращается.

Comment: дайте код Вашей функции, а не цикла в ней

Comment: Вот, я ее вызываю AJAX'ом и должен получить в ответ либо 1, либо 0

Comment: Обновил ответ (AJAX)

Comment: echo тоже пробовал. В каком смысле, кстати, цикл не будет выполнен?

Comment: "И есть подозрение, что цикл не будет выполнен. Начальное значение переменной $i меньше указанного значение в условии цикла."

Comment: О господи, это ж надо было мне так с циклом затупить. Да, в этом дело было, спасибо. А echo я сам пробовал уже до вашего совета